# C++: Binary to Decimal Conversion

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a binary array to decimal in following way:

```
uint8_t array[8] = {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1} ;
int decimal = 0 ;    

for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
    decimal = (decimal << 1) + array[i] ;
```

Actually I have to convert 64 bit binary array to decimal and I have to do it for million times.

Can anybody help me, is there any faster way to do the above ? Or is the above one is nice ?

Comment: It doesn't matter it the bits are in an array or as a string, you have to loop over the bits anyway. There might be more C++ specific ways to do it but in the end there will always be a loop over the bits.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686004/fastest-way-to-convert-binary-to-decimal) may help you

Comment: Usually big optimization benefits can be gained not from small functions, but looking on a higher level. Why the digits are stored in this way?

Comment: You could employ loop unrolling and/or pointer arithmetic instead of array access. That would speed things up but it would remain at the same algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is adequate, to call it *nice* I would just not mix bitwise operations and "mathematical" way of converting to decimal, i.e. use either

```
    decimal = decimal << 1 | array[i];
```

or

```
    decimal = decimal * 2 + array[i];
```

Comment: Note however that any decent compiler will treat the shift and the multiply identically, whereas using an 'or' instead of an add will restrict it's ability to optimise. Indeed, MSVC generates poorer code for the first example here, but the same code for the second case as in the original.

Answer (score 2):

It is important, before attempting any optimisation, to profile the code. Time it, look at the code being generated, and optimise only when you understand what is going on.

And as already pointed out, the best optimisation is to not do something, but to make a higher level change that removes the need.

However...

Most changes you might want to trivially make here, are likely to be things the compiler has already done (a shift is the same as a multiply to the compiler). Some may actually *prevent* the compiler from making an optimisation (changing an `add` to an `or` will restrict the compiler - there are more ways to add numbers, and only you know that in this case the result will be the same).

Pointer arithmetic may be better, but the compiler is not stupid - it ought to already be producing decent code for dereferencing the array, so you need to check that you have not in fact made matters worse by introducing an additional variable.

In this case the loop count is well defined and limited, so unrolling probably makes sense.

Further more it depends on how dependent you want the result to be on your target architecture. If you want portability, it is hard(er) to optimise.

For example, the following produces better code here:

```
unsigned int x0 = *(unsigned int *)array;
unsigned int x1 = *(unsigned int *)(array+4);

int decimal = ((x0 * 0x8040201) >> 20) + ((x1 * 0x8040201) >> 24);
```

I could probably also roll a 64-bit version that did 8 bits at a time instead of 4.

But it is very definitely not portable code. I might use that locally if I knew what I was running on and I just wanted to crunch numbers quickly. But I probably wouldn't put it in production code. Certainly not without documenting what it did, and without the accompanying unit test that checks that it actually works.

Comment: See [How to create a byte out of 8 bool values (and vice versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8461126) for a 64-bit version of the portable bithack.  (And mention of x86 tricks like `pmovmskb`)

Comment: Also, `*(unsigned int *)array` could be strict-aliasing undefined behaviour if it's an actual `char array[8]`, not just a `char*` to anonymous memory.  And could be alignment UB unless you did `alignas(unsigned) char array[8];`.  Use `memcpy(&tmp, array, sizeof(tmp))` to do strict-aliasing-safe unaligned loads.  That can make it full portable, at least to systems where `static_assert(sizeof(uint64_t) == 8)`.  This doesn't depend on endianness or anything, although it does depend on 8-bit bytes.  Types like `uint64_t` are guaranteed to have no padding.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `accumulate`, with a doubling and adding binary operation:

```
int doubleSumAndAdd(const int& sum, const int& next) {
    return (sum * 2) + next;
}

int decimal = accumulate(array, array+ARRAY_SIZE,
                         doubleSumAndAdd);
```

This produces big-endian integers, whereas OP code produces little-endian.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, I converted a binary digit of up to 1020 bits

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long binary_decimal(string num) /* Function to convert binary to dec */
{
    long dec = 0, n = 1, exp = 0;
    string bin = num;
       if(bin.length() > 1020){
          cout << "Binary Digit too large" << endl;
       }
       else {

            for(int i = bin.length() - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                 n = pow(2,exp++);
                 if(bin.at(i) == '1')
                 dec += n;
            }

       }
  return dec;
}
```

Theoretically this method will work for a binary digit of infinate length

Comment: You do realize that `long` is 32 (or 64) bits and you can't actually fit 1020 bits into that?

Comment: Yes..u musy have mis read it. It works like so : bin: 101 dec: 5 i read a string of up to 1020 bits and everytime i reach a 1, I add whatever 2* pow is.

Comment: Try and test your code with a string of more than 31 or 63 bits. You cannot possibly represent value of 1020 bits in a 32 or 64 bit signed integer. The result overflows and wraps around. [Look at your code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/was22Y). When I give it 32 or more bits the result is -1. It should be obvious that `1020` bits can't be represented with a `32` bit variable.

Comment: I'm designing a VM and It works perfically fine, I decoded a 1020 bit binary and stored the result in a double

Comment: This code doesn't use or return `double`. Even if you change it to use `double` you should realize that IEEE 754 double-precision floating point has a significand of 53 bits (about 16 decimal digits). You can't actually store 1020 significant bits in a `double`, it will be an approximation. The only way this works is with some Big Integer library.

Answer (score -4):

here's a lazy way to quickly process it 16-bits at a time without using pointer arithmetic, exponentiation, or bit-shifting/bit-masking, by :

- placing 15 nested copies of `2 * (` on the left side, and
- placing all the array bits on the right side, in big-endian order

---

```
function b2d_16_unsigned(_, __) { 

    # set __[_ = 1] for langs w/ 1-based indexing e.g. julia/lua/awk etc

    return \
    (_ += _ = split(_, __, _ = "")^_\
       )*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_* \
                                                   __[_ = 0] \
       + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
     ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
     ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]
}
```

---

```
1110111110010101 61333
```

so the ***signedness-agnostic*** `64-bit` fully unrolled version would look like

```
function b2d_64(_, signed_flag, __) { # signed_flag is 0/1

    return \
    (_ += _ = split(sprintf("%64s",_), __, _ = "")^_\
     )*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(\
     _*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(\
     _*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(\
     _*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(_*(\
                           (+signed_flag ? -_ : _) * \
                                            __[_ = 0] \
           + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
         ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
         ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
         ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
         ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
         ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
         ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
         ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
         ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
         ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
         ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
         ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_] \
                               ) + __[++_]) + __[++_]) + __[++_]
}
```

---

```
1100010001100001010000100101000110000100110110001101110110110001 0

                                              14150664422063398321

1100010001100001010000100101000110000100110110001101110110110001 1

                                              -4296079651646153295
```

Comment: What language is this?  AWK?  A C++ version of this would have undefined behaviour from unsequenced `++`.  Also, `sprintf` isn't remotely fast compared to simple integer math on `uint64_t`.

Comment: @PeterCordes : the `sprintf()` was only to right-align the input to 64 bytes long there's nothing there about the summation being done via `sprintf()`. Cuz it's either that or an even slower loop to keep checking where the end point is. If you think integer math over `uint64_t` is always the fastest, try calculating `mod 3` against a 50-million decimal digit input. I can almost guarantee you string ops will be waaaay faster than trying to convert them to big-int "limbs"

Comment: @PeterCordes : or say creating a repeating chain of something. If you think doubling is fast, wait till you try string squaring. Just start with 2 copies of whatever is the starting point, and 5 loops of string squaring later, you'll have `2^32` copies of the starting point, because it's simply following the formula `2^32 = 2^2^5`

Comment: A 50-million decimal digit number doesn't fit in a single `uint64_t`.  I was talking about the integer math required for *this* problem, not whatever random example you can make up.

Comment: @PeterCordes : how do you fit a 64-byte `ASCII` binary string in a single `uint64_t` before the conversion process ?

Comment: You don't.  You process it in 8-byte chunks using [How to create a byte out of 8 bool values (and vice versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8461126), or 16 or 32-byte chunks using SSE2 or AVX2 SIMD vectors.  Or with a simple `total = total*2 + digit`.  Anyway, the final *result* is one `uint64_t`, so the widest accumulator you need is a single `uint64_t`

Comment: @PeterCordes : so your solution is vectorized instructions on a dying architecture ?