# What is the faster way to conver BigInteger to array of int?

Tags: java, biginteger

I have BigInt

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("5876934265987526278534978564378568734564937563487564327564376534875483753475");
```

I need to convert it to `[] int`. How can I do this fast?

My method is very slow

```
private static int[] convertDigitsToIntArray(java.math.BigInteger x) {
    String s = x.toString();
    int[] result = new int[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        result[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You must use `Notepad++` or `EditPadPro` and use a macro.. You don't need programming here I think.. you need regular record macro and run it.

Comment: Call `toString()` and then convert each character to an `int`? The `toString` is likely to be fairly well optimised.

Comment: @Alan Stokes It's too slow approach.

Comment: what would your result int[]  be if the bigint is `new BigInteger("-123")`

Comment: I don't have negative values.

Comment: To convert a char to a digit use `Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10)` - that will be much faster than what you have.

Comment: @user It's never going to get a lot faster. Converting to decimal is inherently complex (lots of division). The final step of converting characters to digits is trivial by comparison.

Comment: It would be polite to credit @Nielarshi when you paste his answer in your question.

Comment: If you really need fast conversion to decimal, maybe you should do your computations in decimal instead of binary - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1694615/212870. But I don't know of an existing implementation of that in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Convert it to a string and then iterate the characters:

```
int[] getArr(BigInteger num)
{
    String str = num.toString();
    int[] arr = new int[str.length()];
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
         arr[i] = str.charAt(i)-'0';
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      BigInteger i = new BigInteger("5876934265987526278534978564378568734564937563487564327564376534875483753475");
      String iStr = i.toString();
      int[] intArray = new int[iStr.length()];
      for(int j=0; j<iStr.length(); j++) {
          intArray[j] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(iStr.charAt(j)));
      }
  }
```

Comment: Its too slow solution.

Comment: Define "too slow". Have you measured it? What are the tresholds you have to reach?

Comment: I think this as fast as it could be it uses very little code just substring every character, you can use divide by `1000000, 100000, 10000, 1000, 100, 10` but this will be slower

Comment: What's the difference between this code and the code in the question?

Comment: that was put after my ans was added.. nothing else.. ;)

Comment: ya..i agree..when u have a very large bigint..its slow...hope someone puts optimised code..

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
private static int[] convertDigitsToIntArray(java.math.BigInteger x) {
    String s = x.toString();
    int[] result = new int[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        result[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Java is pass by value, so assigning a new reference to `int[] result` inside the method won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the BigInteger to a String, get the char array of that string and iterate over that:

```
java.math.BigInteger source = new java.math.BigInteger("5876934265987526278534978564378568734564937563487564327564376534875483753475");

char[] array = source.toString().toCharArray();
int[] result = new int[array.length];
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    result[i] = array[i] - '0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int[] convertDigitsToIntArray(java.math.BigInteger x) {
    String s = x.toString();
    int[] result = new int[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        // Change your code to subtract the char '0'
        result[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
    }
    return result;
}
```